# Change the style of last letter in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this structure and I don't have access to modify the markup so I'm looking for a jQuery solution to this:

```
<p>Get a<strong><span>10%</span>discount</strong>in your first buy</p>
```

What I need is the `10` in the span to be `font-size:30px` and the `%` in the span to be `18px`.

I just put this:

```
.p strong span{
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

The `strong` and `p` already have styles so I can't modify it.

But I can't style the `%` that way. Any ideas on how to get the last letter? Again, I don't have access to modify the structure so any other type of solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrap the % inside another `span` with class percentage and set the `font-size` to it.

Comment: css doesn't have very strong sub-string capabilities. use javascript to rip apart the string and wrap the % in another `<span>` and put some classes/styles on those.

Comment: how can I wrap the % in another span?

Comment: @codek See my answer below. If you have control over markup, add a `span` to wrap the `%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to dynamically add percent span:

```js
$('p strong span:contains(%)').html(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace('%', '<span class="percent">%</span>');
});
```

```css
p strong span {
    font-size: 30px;
}
p strong span .percent {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Get a <strong><span>10%</span> discount</strong> in your first buy</p>
```